# How can I set the item icon in the navigation drawer to the right side of the item?

Tags: android, navigation, icons, toggle, drawer

I want the left side icons to remain as they are, I just want one more icon on the right side of the item.
Please check below image, it will help you to understand my requirement.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes sir, but that brings the navigation drawer icon to the right side of the toolbar. I don't want that. I want to bring the item icon to the right.

Comment: use customize layout design for drawer.

Comment: thank u, but i would appreciate if you could provide me the solution

Comment: Hi Harshit Paliwal, You can not do with default menu you need to remove default menu, and need to put view or like list view type of thing.

Comment: refer this;
http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Post what you have tried.that will help you to other developer take you to the right path.

Comment: Complete tutorial refer this link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-sidebar-navigation-drawer-with-icons/

Answer (score -1):

If you are using drawer layout or navigation drawer then it will help you.

Only you need to replace your navigation menu layout with following linear layout and need to remove all the menu related code from activity,

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/places_ic_search"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/places_ic_search"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```